# code HTTP 200 Internal Server Error : The HTTP server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: php, jdeveloper

im trying to get data from my SOAP web service (using WAMPSERVER and php)  to my device.

Im using Jdeveloper 12c.

When i start the application i get this error :

**code HTTP
200 Internal Server Error : The HTTP server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.**

Here is the logs:

```
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpServiceConnection - log] Erreur de connexion : 500

D/JVM     (23519): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpTransport - parseResponse] RÃ©ponse [Erreur : 500] : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

D/JVM     (23519):   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

D/JVM     (23519):   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

D/JVM     (23519):   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

D/JVM     (23519):   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

D/JVM     (23519): <SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing:

D/JVM     (23519): xml was empty, didn&apos;t parse!</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My Connection.xml :

```
<Reference name="gcmService" className="oracle.adf.model.connection.webservice.impl.WebServiceConnectionImpl"
             xmlns="">
    <Factory className="oracle.adf.model.connection.webservice.api.WebServiceConnectionFactory"/>
    <RefAddresses>
      <XmlRefAddr addrType="WebServiceConnection">
        <Contents>
          <wsconnection description="http://192.168.1.3/gcm/myservice.php?wsdl" service="{urn:MyService}MyService">
            <model name="{urn:MyService}MyService" xmlns="http://oracle.com/ws/model">
              <service name="{urn:MyService}MyService">
                <port name="MyServicePort" binding="{urn:MyService}MyServiceBinding">
                  <soap addressUrl="http://192.168.1.3/gcm/myservice.php" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
                  <operation name="insertUserRegistrationId">
                    <soap soapAction="urn:MyServicewsdl#saveNewRegisterUser"
                          xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
                    <input name=""/>
                    <output name=""/>
                  </operation>
                  <operation name="getHistoriqueNotification">
                    <soap soapAction="urn:MyServicewsdl#getHistoriqueNotification"
                          xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
                    <input name=""/>
                    <output name=""/>
                  </operation>
                  <operation name="disconnect">
                    <soap soapAction="urn:MyServicewsdl#disconnect" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
                    <input name=""/>
                    <output name=""/>
                  </operation>
                </port>
              </service>
            </model>
          </wsconnection>
        </Contents>
      </XmlRefAddr>
    </RefAddresses>
  </Reference>
</References>
```

And my service.php implementing SOAP web service :

```
<?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
 require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'database.php';
// Create the server instance
$server = new soap_server();
// Initialize WSDL support
$server->configureWSDL('MyService', 'urn:MyService');
                // Character encoding
                $server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
                //-------------------------------------------------


                //Register function

                       $server->register('insertUserRegistrationId',
                        array('$user'=>'xsd:string','$mdp'=>'xsd:string','$registration_id'=>'xsd:string'),
                        array('return' =>'xsd:boolean'),
                          'urn:MyServicewsdl',
                        'urn:MyServicewsdl#saveNewRegisterUser',
                        'rpc',
                        'encoded',
                        'Some comments about function 1'
                    );
                       $server->register('getHistoriqueNotification',
                        array('$registration_id'=>'xsd:string'),
                        array('return' =>'xsd:string'),
                          'urn:MyServicewsdl',
                        'urn:MyServicewsdl#getHistoriqueNotification',
                        'rpc',
                        'liternal',
                        'Some comments about function 2'
                    );
$server->register('disconnect',
                        array(),
                        array(),
                          'urn:MyServicewsdl',
                        'urn:MyServicewsdl#disconnect',
                        'rpc',
                        'literal',
                        'Some comments about function 3'
                    );

                //-------------------------------------------------



                 $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)
   ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
        ?>
```

Comment: It's odd that you're seeing an HTTP *200* response code for an internal server error. That should probably be an HTTP *500* Internal Server Error.